# Enabling Code Folding Bar in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-folding

How to enable the code folding bar next to the line numbers?

I googled "code folding Mac"; it's all about triggering code folding and unfolding, but nothing about enabling the bar.

I have tried using `Editor -> Code Folding  -> Fold/Unfold` to fold and unfold codes, but I don't have the vertical bar there next to the line numbers; so, I have the button to click to fold and unfold.

How can I enable that bar?

[image: Please see image here here].

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I always encounter this that suddenly I accidentally hide the Code folding ribon. So from @PetahChristian's answer, I captured it with screenshot.

Xcode > Settings > Text Editing > Check "Code Folding Ribbon"

You may also access Settings through shortcut command + ,

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no such Preference exists in Xcode 9.2

Comment: The setting may have vanished temporarily from Xcode 9, but it is still present as of Xcode 12.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Preferences -> Text Editing, and click **Show code folding ribbon**.

Answer (score 9):

Code folding was disabled in Xcode 9 beta 1, which is working now, in Xcode 9 Beta5 according to beta release note: [Resolved in Xcode 9 beta 5 – IDE](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_5/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_9_beta_5.pdf)

Here is how:

1. Press and hold **`⌘`** (command) button in keyboard and move/hover mouse cursor on any (start or end) braces. It will automatically highlight, block area.
2. Keep (hold) **`⌘`** (command) button in pressed condition and click on highlighted area. It will enable quick menu popover window with **`Fold`** option.
3. Select **`Fold`** from menu list. It will fold your code and shows 3 dots, folding/covering entire block.
4. Now, to again unfold your code block, release **`⌘`** (command) button and click on 3 dots folding a block.

**For easy understanding, look at this snapshot:**

[image]

It's all keyboard short cuts are also working.

```
Fold                          ⌥ ⌘ ←      option + command + left arrow
Unfold                        ⌥ ⌘ →      option + command + right arrow
Unfold All                    ⌥ U        option + U
Fold Methods & Functions      ⌥ ⌘ ↑      option + command + up arrow
Unfold Methods & Functions    ⌥ ⌘ ↓      option + command + down arrow
Fold Comment Blocks           ⌃ ⇧ ⌘ ↑    control + shift + command + up
Unfold Comment Blocks         ⌃ ⇧ ⌘ ↓    control + shift + command + down
Focus Follows Selection       ⌃ ⌥ ⌘ F    control + option + command + F
Fold All                      ⌘ ⌥ ⇧ ←    command + option + shift + left
Unfold All                    ⌘ ⌥ ⇧ →    command + option + shift + left
```

**Code folding options from Xcode Menu**:

> Menubar  ►  Editor  ►  Code Folding  ►  "Here is list of code folding options"

Here is ref snapshot:

[image]

**Same options from Xcode Short-cut list**:

> Menubar  ►  Xcode  ►  Preferences  ► Key Bindings ► "Here is list of code folding short-keys"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer for Xcode 12 and above
Code folding ribbon is quite useful and easy to view code scope.

Go to Preferences -> Text Editing -> Display, and click on Code folding ribbon

[image]